# Как обойти все файлы в папке и подпапках и добавить текст в каждый файл в С шарп?

Tags: c#, файлы

```
            Корневая Папка
        /         |         \
  Папка А       Папка Б       Папка В 
/    |   \     / | \       /    |    \
```

1.txt   2.txt           3.txt  . . .  n-2.txt         n-1.txt         n.txt

Как обойти все файлы в папке и подпапках и добавить текст в каждый файл в С шарп? Добавление текста в конец файла. Хотелось бы узнать, как можно сделать это хотя бы рекурсивно в С шарп.

Comment: Вот это Вам подойдет к дополнению ответа от PashPash. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1205176/397512

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string rootFolder = @"c:\temp";
foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(rootFolder, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    File.AppendAllText(file, "текст для добавления");
}
```

Comment: Таки скорее всего надо по маске `*.txt*` искать, а то напортачить можно.

Comment: @PashaPash♦ мне такую ошибку выдает + $exception {System.NotSupportedException: Данный формат пути не поддерживается. в System.Security.Util.StringExpressionSet.CanonicalizePath(String path, Boolean needFullPath) в System.Security.Util.StringExpressionSet.CreateListFromExpressions(String[] str, Boolean needFullPath)