# Получить все txt файлы с компьютера

Tags: c#, winforms, системное-программирование

Можно ли как-то получить путь ко всем .txt файлам на ПК, или просто скопировать их все в одну папку?

Comment: Конечно [можно](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/303974/how-to-recursively-search-directories-by-using-visual-c) (30 секунд искал), рекурсивный поиск по маске к вашим услугам.

Comment: Класс DirectoryInfo Вам в помощь. Вам нужно самому написать рекурсивную функцию, которая для текущей директории анализирует файлы, которые в ней находится, а затем вызывает себя для всех дочерних директрорий

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот пример функции, решающей Вашу проблему:

```
    static public void FindFiles(string pathname, ref List<FileInfo> files_list, ref List<DirectoryInfo> dir_list)
    {
        DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(pathname);

        if (dinfo.Exists)
        {
            // Получить массив файлов в текущей папке
            try
            {
                FileInfo[] files = dinfo.GetFiles();
                foreach (FileInfo current in files)
                {
                    files_list.Add(current);
                }

                // Получить массив подпапок в текущей папке
                DirectoryInfo[] dirs = dinfo.GetDirectories();
                foreach (DirectoryInfo current in dirs)
                {
                    dir_list.Add(current);
                    FindFiles(pathname + @"\" + current.Name, ref files_list, ref dir_list);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Path is not exists");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Зачем передавать ссылочный тип по ссылке, и не проверять его на null?

Comment: Хм...так это рекурсивная функция...хочешь проверить на нуль, сделай ей обертку. А для общего случая try catch предусмотрен. Нужно осознавать что все написанное в этой функции будет выполнять каждый раз при вызове этой функции...и зачастую в пустую. Я бы даже try catch вынес из нее. И как написано это пример.

Comment: `ref List` - это конечно перегнул, так как `List` сам по себе ссылка.